# Printing just the dict value

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why my loop is printing everything in the dict and not just the values

```
films = {
"2005": ["Munich", "Steven Spielberg"], 
"2006": [["The Prestige", "Christopher Nolan"], ["The Departed", "Martin Scorsese"]]
}

    for year in movies:
        print (year)
        for x in films[year]:
            print (films[year])
```

I would like it to print like this

```
2005
Munich, Steven Spielberg

2006
The prestige, Christopher Nolan
the Departed, Martin Scorsese
```

But instead its printing like this with brackets and apostrophes

```
2005
['Munich', 'Steven Spielberg']
```

Comment: You're passing a *list* to `print()`, so it's gonna print it like that.  If you want a *string*, you can try using `join()`.  Also your dist doesn't have consistent data, sometimes it's a list of strings, other times it's a list of lists (of strings).

Comment: You're printing `films[year]` rather than `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using **x** (I suggest a better name).

This code works in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x:

```
films = {
"2005": ["Munich", "Steven Spielberg"], 
"2006": [["The Prestige", "Christopher Nolan"], ["The Departed", "Martin Scorsese"]]
}

for year in sorted(films.keys()):
    print(year)
    if isinstance(films[year][0], list):
        films_list = films[year]
    else:
        films_list = [films[year]]
    for film in films_list:
        print(", ".join(film))
    print("")
```

Comment: Why did you get rid of the `movies` variable?  They might not want to print every key.

Comment: I just renamed it to **films**, because you use it in the `for` loop

Comment: Yes but "movies" might be something else - a list of years from a search result, for example.  We don't have enough context to assume, here.

Comment: Enough context must be provided in every question on SO so we don't "assume" anything.

Comment: Edited the sample code to handle the case of a simple list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print (films[year])
```

use

```
print (", ".join(films[x]))
```

This construction joins members of the list `films[x]` (yes - `[x]`, not `[year]`) using the string
`", "` (comma and a space) as separators between individual members.